# Batyrev's theorem in non-algebraic case

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two bimeromorphic closed Kaehler manifolds with trivial real $c_1$. Is it true that $b_n(X)=b_n(Y)$ for $n\geq 0$?

Comment: Welcome, new contributor.  One of my colleagues points out that for hyperKaehler manifolds, this result is true regardless of algebraicity, since then the manifolds are even deformation equivalent.